# estimate server cost using aws

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, web

pardon me if this isn't the place to ask such question. But I have finished my project and thinking to deploy it using amazon elastic beanstalk and got a huge worry. My worry is that my project's database can be humongous. It's a community website like a reddit that users can create a page that other people can post text,link,pic,video(youtube). Also users get a profile page, and are able to comment as well. This was my first big project, and I don't want to pay more than $200 for server fee every month. 
should I still deploy this? or just be happy I proved myself I can make this? how much do you think I'll have to pay assuming I get about (max)100 users?

Comment: You mention a "humongous" database  but no exact size, $200 and 100 users.  That simply isn't enough information for a specific question.  It's also off topic for Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you can look at the costs for any AWS service by going to that services 'homepage' and clicking "Pricing" usually on the left side.  I typically get to the pricing page by Googling "AWS <> Pricing" (e.g. "AWS EC2 Pricing").

Whether or not you incur any cost and what that cost is, really depends on how you deploy your website.  Questions like, is your database self-managed (i.e. installed on your own EC2 instance) or are you using RDS?  Are you using S3 to store static content?  Will you be serving your web contents via Cloudfront (AWS' CDN)?

Many of the basic services (EC2, S3, RDS, etc.) have free-tiers which will allow you to use them for free, provided you stay within certain (and usually very low) levels of usage.

If your database is going to get VERY large, and cost is your primary concern, it's usually more cost-effective to manage it on your own EC2 server, however then things like updates, security, scaling, backups, etc. all become your problem to deal with and often can incur additional cost (i.e. your backups will likely require volume snapshots which will cost you vs. RDS' backups are free).

If you're going to have a significant amount of static content, it will be more cost effective to host it on your own EC2 server, however again, all maintenance will be your responsibility, such as backups and scaling (which can incur cost) to meet demand vs. all of that is taken care of by S3, though you pay each time a file is accessed.

If cost is your primary concern, my suggestion is to start out your development using the AWS services (RDS, S3 maybe Elastic Beanstalk), though that can often complexity to your development efforts (dealing with authentication, additional SDK's, etc.).  You can typically and pretty easily roll out your own service (MySQL, EBS filesystem to replace S3, etc.) as replacement.  Additionally, again depending on your roll-out, there can be network traffic costs.  Usually, this isn't a problem if you're doing things the way Amazon wants you to, but...it wouldn't be unheard of.

To get you started:

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/
https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/

Additionally, there is a nifty calculator which can help you estimate your costs.  You will need to know what your traffic expectations as well as service requirements are, but you can play around with those numbers.

https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about charges. As AWS has a Free tier which offers most of the services free for 12 months.
https://aws.amazon.com/free/

You can have 01 t2.micro (1 vCpu + 1 gb RAM) instance for Elastic beanstalk (EBS) with auto scaling turned off, purchase Reserved instances by making 1 or 3 year all upfront payment to save more.
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/

You must use Relational Database Service (RDS) for database, instead of installing db in your EBS instance & store files on Simple Storage Service (S3).
RDS Pricing is $0.100 per GB-month, after first 12 months. So you dont need to worry about the database size.

After first 12 months, your monthly bill would be less than USD 50.
On production, we are using 2 t2.micro instances (Windows) with 1 Ms Sql database on RDS & we only have to pay for the extra EC2 machine, about USD 14 per month.

Answer (score 0):

I did find some relevant information in the below stackoverflow thread which talks about the capabilities of t2.micro,t2.small &  t2.medium ec2 instances.Do have a look at it.

[several t2.micro better than a single t2.small or t2.medium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755889/several-t2-micro-better-than-a-single-t2-small-or-t2-medium)